# Why can I access only one global variable in my views? The rest throw reference errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In **app.js** I created a global variable to access in all views:    `app.locals.siteTitle = 'Node Express';`

My **articles.ejs** (view) renders it correctly. However, when I add another global variable like this: `app.locals.sillyMessage = 'What the hello!';`, it throws a **reference error** and tells me that **sillyMessage is not defined**.

Comment: Can you possibly provide some more context? When/where is `app.locals.sillyMessage` being set and when is the view being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit silly on my part but:

The server had to be restarted in order to process the changes in app.js before those variables could be initialized or used locally in views.

In order to prevent this issue in the future I added nodemon.js to watch for file changes in the directory and reload.js to update the page when a change is detected.